# React usestate set method not changing value even after timeout

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I have a situation where the set method of useState is not changing the value.  I know that this is an async function so I put the set method in a timeout function and then output the values in a console log to check the value.  I output the same values to console log in another timeout function, both with 5 second wait times.  Nothing else is running on the server.

The snipped of code is below.  The set method that is not working is, "setGroupUsersRemoved(userListToRemove)".  I have this in two places, one where I want it to run and a second time in a time out.  The api remove call executes as witnessed by the console logs so that is not the issue.  I have two other (useState) set methods in the code and they are both working fine.

The console log shows the value of the variable, userListToRemove, to have 3 entries in the array but the variable, groupUsersRemoved, never gets set.

Appreciate any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong.

Here is my intializtion.

`const [groupUsersRemoved,setGroupUsersRemoved] = useState([]);`

Here is the code where I use the setMethod

```
  const deleteGroup = (idToDelete) => {
    const indexToDelete = findMatchingIndex(idToDelete);
    console.log("GroupAccessForm - indexToDelete = " + indexToDelete );
    if (indexToDelete >= 0)
    {
      if (groupAccessListing[indexToDelete].owner_id === userId )
      {
        console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - userList = ", groupAccessListing[indexToDelete].userList );
        let userListToRemove = []
        for (let i =0; i<groupAccessListing[indexToDelete].userList.length; i++)
        {
          userListToRemove.push(groupAccessListing[indexToDelete].userList[i].id);
        }
        console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - userListToRemove = ", userListToRemove );
        setGroupUsersRemoved(userListToRemove);
        console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - selected = " + selected );
        remove(
          { groupId:  idToDelete}, 
          {t: jwt.token}).then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            console.log(data.error)
            setNotify({
              isOpen: true,
              message: "Group not removed! Please try again.. Notify Administrator if problem persists.",
              type: "error",
            });
          } else {
            console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - idToDelete = " + idToDelete );
            if (indexToDelete >= 0)
            { console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - indexToDelete >=0 = " + indexToDelete );
              setGroupAccessListing ( [...groupAccessListing.slice(0, indexToDelete), // everything before current post
                                      ...groupAccessListing.slice(indexToDelete + 1)]) // everything after current post
              setGroupAccessListingPreFilter (  [...groupAccessListingPreFilter.slice(0, indexToDelete), // everything before current post
                                              ...groupAccessListingPreFilter.slice(indexToDelete + 1) ])// everything after current post
              console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - userList = " + groupAccessListing[indexToDelete].userList );
              

              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - userListToRemove = ", userListToRemove );
                console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - groupUsersRemoved = ", groupUsersRemoved );
                setGroupUsersRemoved(userListToRemove);   
              }, 5000);  

              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - userListToRemove = ", userListToRemove );
                console.log("GroupAccessForm - deleteGroup() - groupUsersRemoved = ", groupUsersRemoved );
                removeGroupsFromUserMembership(idToDelete);   
              }, 5000);                     
            } 
        
          }
        })
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use useEffect hook for state you want to control.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    /* do something when groupUsersRemoved state changed */ 
}, [groupUsersRemoved])
```

You can also listen for other state changes just by putting theirs name in array which is second argument of useEffect.

Comment: This works in most situations but as I do not want to do something every time and the actions may vary it would complicate the useEffect so have avoided doing this.  I was able to solve by running it through another function. I will show my answer in another section.  I would be interested in better understanding, why, even after a 5 second delay, the set method did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by calling another function that ran the set method.  Code below.

```
 const trackUsersAddedAndRemoved = (addedOrRemoved, idChanged) => {
    const addIndex = findIdInArray(groupUsersAdded, idChanged);
    const removeIndex = findIdInArray(groupUsersRemoved, idChanged);

    console.log("GroupAccessForm -trackUsersAddedAndRemoved-before Add/remove-groupUsersAdded", groupUsersAdded);
    console.log("GroupAccessForm -trackUsersAddedAndRemoved-before Add/remove-groupUsersRemoved", groupUsersRemoved);
    console.log("GroupAccessForm -trackUsersAddedAndRemoved-addedOrRemoved", addedOrRemoved);
    console.log("GroupAccessForm -trackUsersAddedAndRemoved-idChanged", idChanged);
   let newAddUsersTogroup = groupUsersAdded;
   let newRemoveUsersFromGroup = groupUsersRemoved
   if (addedOrRemoved ==="Add")
    {
      if (addIndex < 0)
      {
        newAddUsersTogroup.push(idChanged);
      }
      if (removeIndex >= 0)
      {
        newRemoveUsersFromGroup.splice(removeIndex,1)
      }
    } else if (addedOrRemoved ==="Remove")
    {
      if (removeIndex < 0)
      {
        newRemoveUsersFromGroup.push(idChanged);
      }
      if (addIndex >= 0)
      {
        newAddUsersTogroup.splice(addIndex,1)
      }
    }
    setGroupUsersAdded(newAddUsersTogroup);
    setGroupUsersRemoved(newRemoveUsersFromGroup);
  }
```